# Dynamics CRM limit "regarding" lookup field for only 1 entity on Appointment form and set default view for "Look in"

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to limit entities that the user can select from on "Regarding" field on Appointment form and set some default views used by these lookup fields.

The big idea is that when user is entering data in the field itself, the results should be provided from default view for this lookup, e.g. "Contacts I follow", but when user enters "Lookup more records" pop-up the default view should be swapped to "All contacts".

This field can look up in many entities, e.g. Account, Contact, Billing, etc., and I want to limit it strictly to Accounts only.

#### So far I've found two ways of doing it:

1) Add filters to lookup fields, so that any records not fulfilling  given criteria will not be shown. This is done using `addPreSearch` JS function from `Xrm` lib, like this:

```
var addEventHandler = function (defaultView) {
    Xrm.Page.getControl("contactid").addPreSearch(function () {
        addFilter("contactid", defaultView) 
    });
}

var addFilter = function (entityName, defaultView) {
    var filterXml = "<filter type = 'and'>" +
                        "<condition attribute='contactid' operator='null'/>" +
                    "</filter>";

    Xrm.Page.getControl("contactid").addCustomFilter(filterXml, "contact");
    Xrm.Page.getControl("contactid").setDefaultView(defaultView);
}
```

(This is just sample code, not actually applied to the Regarding field)

2) Second option is to use undocumented solution by using `setLookupTypes` function on the field itself, like this:

```
var limitLookupEntities = function () {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("contactid").setLookupTypes(["contact"]);
}

var changeDefaultViewForLookup = function(viewGuid){
    Xrm.Page.getControl("contactid").setDefaultView(viewGuid);
}
```

#### The issue:

The problem is that as mentioned earlier, "Regarding" field can look up in many entities. Limiting them using the solution 1) is tedious, having to create as many filters as there are entities and applying them one by one to the field doesn't seem the right way to go. However, the way I implement this, the default view behaviour works as intended - the look-in value is only changed for the pop-up window.

Solution 2) is way easier to implement, and won't require any changes in the future if any new entities would be added to relationship with "Regarding" field, but the default view is applied to both "in-field" and "pop-up" default view.

The solution I'm looking for needs to do the following:

1. It should limit the search to specified entity only
2. It shouldn't require any maintaining after being implemented, e.g.
   in case new entities are introduced to "Regarding" field.
3. It should be generic - I might want to be able to parametrize it and use it on other forms
4. It should apply the default view change only when user opens the pop-up search window

Is it even possible?

The CRM version I'm implementing this on is 8.2 on-prem.

Comment: What did you end up with?

Comment: IIRC I just explained to stakeholders that such functionality is not recommended in CRM, as it may cause more issues than good. Sorry for disappointing news :(

Comment: that’s fine. I was wondering whether all this complex implementation is worth if at all :) as these can be fixed by simply user training